# How do I style a checkbox label in GXT

Tags: gxt

Here is code that works:

```
    myCheckBox = new CheckBox();
    myCheckBox.setBoxLabel("my checkbox label");
```

I put this in a panel and it creates a checkbox that is clickable, as well a label that when clicked toggles the checkbox.

Here is how I think I should add label styling, but this doesn't work.
        myCheckBox.setLabelStyle(myCheckBoxLabelStyle);

Nothing I do to set the label style works.

```
    setStyleName();     
    setStyleAttribute();        
    addStyleName(); 
    setLabelStyle();
```

I was able to create a separate Label element, style it, put a click handler on it and have the click handler set the checkbox value, but I think that's just wrong to have to do.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can style the box label would be to subclass Checkbox and access the protected `boxLabelEl` element directly.

Comment: So it seems as I supposed, no way to do this directly.  I need to choose between mucking around with the internals of a third party library or adding a separate label element with a listener. In the interest of limiting breakability due to later library releases, I'm going to go with the separate label.  Thanks for your suggestion though.